# How to permanently change the IP address of Ubuntu with CLI only?

Tags: command-line, networking, server, ip

I have a ubuntu machine and want to change the IP address,
the requirements are as follow:-

- using only cli to change the IP address, since the HW is not accessible and the script is changing the IP address through SSH, so it has to be the only cli
- The changes to be permanent, the IP address shouldn't be lost on restart
- This should be applicable to all the version of ubuntu

The ubuntu in question is a VM with the default static IP already configured can be accessed with the SSH.

Is there any way to change the IP address of ubuntu with the above requirement?

preferably it should be supported from version 14 - 20 (only stable build)

Comment: How did you get the original address, the one you are trying to change? DHCP, ifupdown, static, netplan ...

Comment: it is snapshot of VM, hence IP is pre-configured, need to change that.

Comment: yes, its static IP allocation

Comment: To start with, which  release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Answer (score 4):

Two (of many ways) to do it, say you want the new IP to be 192.168.80.10 with netmask 255.255.255 and your interface is eth0

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.80.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

or, with the newer `ip` command, you remove the old address and add the new one:

```
$ sudo ip address del old.ip.address/netmask dev eth0
$ sudo ip address add 192.168.80.10/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: will it, instantly apply the IP address?

Comment: @rahulKushwaha yes

Comment: This won't be permanent though, it won't survive a reboot

Comment: As @BobVale stated, this didn't survive a reboot. So I found a way and shared it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1466086/959929)

Answer (score 1):

I did try with the `ip` method shared [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243748/959929), but it did not survive reboots. So, I figured, since the Network Manager was managing stuff, things went back to default

## Change `ip` and `netmask` with `nmcli`

Network Manager is installed by default on ubuntu machines so you have access to `nmcli`. Here is what might work for you:

Check current settings with executing only `nmcli`. Take note on connection *type* (e.g. ethernet), *DNS Configuration* (i.e. servers), and the *interface* you are connecting to.

### Create a new connection

Let's assume you want to create a connection which has the following properties:

1. Name: *SOME_NAME*
2. Interface: *enp0s31f6*
3. The interface *enp0s31f6* is a cable connection, so type is: *ethernet*
4. You want to set the static ip `172.18.1.30`, so set it as `ip4` value and also set `ipv4.type` as `manual`.
5. The default gateway and dns are already shown when entering `nmcli`, if you are not planning to change it, just copy them here as values after `gw4` and `ipv4.dns`,

> Note that autocomplete should work, so you can simply check for things such as *interface-name* by pressing `TAB` twice.

```bash
nmcli # check the previous settings
sudo nmcli connection add connection.id "SOME_NAME" \
                          connection.interface-name enp0s31f6 \
                          type ethernet \
                          ip4 172.18.1.30 gw4 172.18.1.1 \
                          ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8" \
                          ipv4.method manual
sudo nmcli connection up SOME_NAME
nmcli # check the current settings
sudo systemctl restart networking.service
```

Now, the changes should be permanent

This answer was inspired by [this HTG post](https://www.howtogeek.com/839969/how-to-set-a-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).